# Not getting improvements by using CDN

Tags: performance, optimization, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I've just added a CDN distribution using Amazon Cloudfront to my Rails application on Heroku, it's working OK.

My homepage serves around 11 static assets, I've made some tests using http://www.webpagetest.org/ and there are no differences (in terms of performance, optimizing load times) between using the CDN or not.

Is there any particular reason why this could be happening?

My region is Latin America btw, so it's using the All locations edge option.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the two reports, the before and after?

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos here there are:  

Without CDN vs CDN:  


Load time: 3.7s  Load Time: 3.54s


Start Render: 1.822    Start Render: 2.09s  

Speed Index:  2.6s     Speed Index:  2.2s

Comment: I understand is a difference, and CDN is making "some" progress. This has been run 36 times, and the results are similar, but I don't believe that's all that it can help, +-200ms it's just not that much

Comment: Did you try from another part of the world? Use the advanced settings and select other places.

Comment: Actually +-200ms may be a lot! It depends on the scale. And since CloudFront is also a cache, your application will receive a lot less repeated requests.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AnthonyHatzopoulos, I tried from different regions, and they differ, and saving big time, 2 s at most ! What's your theory backing up this hypothesis?

Comment: And thank you for that information @ArturCzajka, I believe that from your comment I can imply that if the Cloudfront it's used more and more it will yield better results?

Comment: @gracegimon The second and following requests, that are served from the same CF endpoint, will be much faster. Please, check the docs for CF regarding Cache-Control response header to get a better grip on this mechanism.

Comment: @gracegimon the reason you see big saving when you check different regions is because the end user doesn't have to fetch resources from a far away origin server. The CDN geoip locates the end user, determines their closest edge server. The end user uses the closer and subsequently quicker edge server to download the resources thus saving strain on your server and feeling snappier and quicker to the visitor. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn

Comment: Thanks. This was definitely helpful, and now, that the CDN has been running for a while, I see great improvements on the different regions near mine.! Thanks a lot @AnthonyHatzopoulos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefits of using CDN from Amazon or others is that they are hosted on fast and reliable servers and offload the traffic served directly from your server, which in case that you have a dedicated fast server you won't see a considerable boost.

But another benefit is that they are potentially cached by user's browser (due to visiting other websites which have used the same CDN) so the visitor will have a better experience first time they visit your site.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestinos.

If the site CSS is one of the static assets that you have moved to CloudFront then I would try moving it back to your main server.

Since page display can't start until the site CSS is downloaded, you want to serve this as fast as possible. If it's coming from a CDN then it requires a second HTTP request.

Also, use the waterfall display from webpagetest.org to pinpoint where the bottlenecks are.

Good luck!